# parameters in WSO2 API manager

Tags: url-routing, wso2-api-manager

I am creating an API with URI template patient/{name} and production URL to http://localhost:8888/patient/{uri.var.name} in WSO2 APIM. Also adding this sequence

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestSequence">
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
</sequence>
```

The target URL is not being invoked with this. Can you please let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur due to Invalid URI provided by you, make sure you are using valid endpoint url for the Production Endpoint.